# Como inserir valor no input em Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic, input, app

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com uma dúvida e até o momento não encontrei nenhuma solução, preciso passar um valor do banco de dados para o input na tela de login, porém não encontrei como fazer isso. O meu código responsável por favor o formulário é este aqui:

```
  <form class="login-form auth-form" [formGroup]="formulario" (ngSubmit)="login()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Informe seu login</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="login" name='login'></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <show-hide-container>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Informe sua senha</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password" name='password' show-hide-input></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </show-hide-container>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Lembrar login</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox color="primary" formControlName="remember" name="remember" checked='false'></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
    
    <button ion-button block class="auth-action-button login-button" name="buttonSubmit" type="submit" [disabled]="!login.valido">Entrar</button>
    
  </form>
```

A função que eu quero fazer para alterar o valor do campo estaria dentro do ngOnInit(),já tenho a variável com o valor porém não consigo inserir esse valor dentro do input "Login", agradeço desde já a ajuda de vocês.

Comment: Mas qual o problema, não é só fazer data binding no input?

Comment: Faltava eu descobrir qual ação fazer, pesquisei por data binding aqui e finalmente consegui fazer, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com a ajuda do LeAndrade, consegui resolver meu problema, coloquei no código do input o ngModel, ficando assim:

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="myvariable" type="text" formControlName="login" name='login'></ion-input>
```

depois no arquivo ts, declarei no export a variável "myvariavel" e no código eu coloquei

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myvariable =  this.getLastLogged();
  }
```

dessa maneira eu consegui adicionar ao input o valor que eu queria!